# Identifying sans-serif logo font with rounded cut corners

Tags: font-identification, sans-serif

I saw this font on a logo and I need to use it on a software I'm creating. I've run it through several websites that try to identify it and none of them work.

[image]

Comment: If you have tried multiple font identification websites and none of them can identify it, then maybe it is not a font at all.  It could well be a group of letters that a designer created just for a one-off design.  Sorry, I know this doesn't help with your problem...

Comment: That's an interesting idea! It hadn't occured to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just a simple font like [Helvetica Bold Italic](https://www.download-free-fonts.com/details/115148/helvetica-neue-bold-italic) that's been hand edited.

In my (very) rough version below I used that font, kerned it out to +115 and "created outlines" with <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>

Then I used the Convert Anchor Point tool <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to round the corner.

Good luck!
[image]